# request.POST.get() is giving None

Tags: django

```
class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def post(self,request):
        email = request.POST.get('Email')
        password = request.POST.get('Password')
        print(email)
        print(password)

        API_KEY = GetAPIkey().api_key_token()
        API_URL = GetAPIurl().api_url_token()
        parameter = {
            'authToken':API_KEY,
            'email':email,
            'password':password,
        }
        url = '{}{}'.format(API_URL,'/rest/storeLogin')
        r = requests.post(url = url, params=parameter)
        print(r.url)
        print(request.user)
        return HttpResponse(r)
```

I am trying to get data from request.POST method, but it is sending me NONE value everytime  when i print email and password. Where am i wrong?Am i doing ajax call wrong? when i was using form submi for ajax calling it was working fine but now i use button click for ajax call.

```
<form class="my-login-form"  id="sanjh_login_form" method="post" url="/login">
                                  {% csrf_token %}
                                <div id="login-data"></div>

                                <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input id='id_login-email' type="email" name="Email" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Id">
                              </div>
                                <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input id='id_login-password' type="password" name="Password" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                                  <button id="login-btn" type="button" class="button button-block" >Login</button>
                                <div class="forgot"><a class="user-form-toggle" href="#forgot">Forgot Password?</a></div>
                              </form>
```

ajax call

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#login-btn').click(function(event){
        console.log('hi-login')

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/login',
            data: {
            email : $('#id-login-email').val(),
            password : $('#id-login-password').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'
            },

            success: function(res) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(res)
                console.log(response.msg)
                      $('#login-data').html(response.msg);
                    },

        })

    })

})

</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried logging `request.data` and `request.POST` ?

Comment: @Umair Logging means?

Comment: Can you add the result of `print(request.POST)`?

Comment: @JPG  print(request.POST) = `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['mRDgde8EsXrwIw7bT2W4sNFxO74LuiwVrZ72ZzQwKSkBHChTlpNf3e0ZmAtKqA32']}>`

Comment: @JPG only middlewaretokken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than giving an answer with code, I'll tell you how to debug such issues:

1. Since the values are `None` you can conclude that your ajax call doesn't pass keys "Email" and "Password". Indeed, when I look at your code, your ajax data is set to "email" and "password". That's your first errors.
2. Next, you printed `request.POST` and saw that even "email" and "password" aren't passed. Looking at how the values are fetched from your form, I see you're looking for id's "id-login-email" and "id-login-password", which don't exist in your HTML (you have "id_login-email" and "id_login-password"). So there's your second mistake.
3. If there are more issues, try setting breakpoints in your javascript (e.g. on the line `$.ajax`) and check the values you're assigning using the console, e.g. type `$(#id_login-email).val()` in your console to check it's the correct value.
4. Finally, always print or add a breakpoint in your `post()` method to view the contents of `request.POST`, it's the best way to understand what the client is actually submitting.

Comment: hi thanks for your valuable insight, now i  fixed point 2 and 3,fixed id name and accessing same in data of ajax and typed iin console its giving typed result, i can see in console my data in console but when i try to get it through request.POST.get('email') its still showing none

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case, but could it be that when you click the button, the form is actually submitted directly by the browser? Normally you'd probably want to prevent default form submission by adding `event.preventDefault()` in your `click()` callback. If that doesn't help please print again `request.POST` at the beginning of your `post()` method and show us the result.

Answer (score 3):

In my case `request.POST.get('value')` not work.
But `request.data.get('value')` worked.
Try this.

Comment: Nice! This works for me

Answer (score 1):

Kindly fix your id attribute value of email and password text fields and retry.

```
<input id='id-login-email' type="email" name="Email" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Id">
<input id='id-login-password' type="password" name="Password" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
```

and also key value in your view

```
email = request.POST.get('email')
password = request.POST.get('password')
```

Once you make these working try refactoring to use `request.data` instead of `request.POST`

Comment: are you accesing input through type? or name?

Comment: Through the keys that you're passing in data field of ajax call.

Comment: no,same, just csrf token and its value.. it giving none for email and password

Comment: Please try debugging a little more, maybe you can try passing hardcoded value in ajax call, if that works then debug your js code , something like that

Comment: Now in console its showing email and password when i  hard code it there.. but i dont understand why its not giving data to views.py where i do have request.POST.get call?

Answer (score -1):

I got that problem in when using input search

```
search = request.POST.get('search')
```

this returned me a "None"

```
<input type='text'/>
```

request.POST.get('search') |  you should add a "name" attribute to your input to use this POST.get() method

```
<input type='text' name = 'search' />
```

soo simple...